# Can't find installed dependencies in Docker container in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg

I have a setup which spins a docker container in Jenkins and after that I want to run some commands in relation to the installed packages.In this example we try to lint the project via `eslint`. `eslint` is in `package.json` so it should be installed when running `yarn install`. I've wasted a lot of time to solve this so any help resolving this is much appreciated

**Jenkins file**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
     label 'linux'
    }

    stage('Test') {
      agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.builder'
            dir '.'
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh label: '', script: 'yarn lint'
      }
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile.builder**

```
FROM node:14.17.4-alpine

WORKDIR /tools

COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile && yarn cache clean

COPY . ./
```

**Errors**

```
warning Cannot find a suitable global folder. Tried these: "/usr/local, /.yarn"
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable.
warning Selected the next writable cache folder in the list, will be "/tmp/.yarn-cache-1500".
warning Cannot find a suitable global folder. Tried these: "/usr/local, /.yarn"
/bin/sh: eslint: not found
```

Comment: What are the contents of your package.json? I can't see anything immediately wrong with this approach.